# Rewrite Rules to just add .php not working

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

So I have a few files like
about.php
contact.php etc

I'm trying to set up rewrite rules so that I can access them through /about and /contact

To do this I've got the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my simple rewrite rule to rewrite only if the file does not exist.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.php
```

If its not wirking you should check if you have set `AllowOverride all` in your vhost configuration. Otherwise the rewrite rule is not working.